# How to implement a parser/component for multiple emails addresses as in the field "To:" in Gmail?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, email

Is that available as part of some Google API or something like that?

[Example of the how Gmail handle multiple email adresses.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MQrM.png)

Notice how it embrace each address with a kind of a box with an "x" option in the right side. It also highlight wrong adresses. I couldn't even properly search it because I don't know its name.

I would like to get some tips on how to implement the same on my web application.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, post it in the question as well. If you're making a webapp, you could use this library https://sean.is/poppin/tags

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this in Asp.Net MVC or Webforms? In MVC, you can use a multi select, Telerik actually has a bindable select control that meets your exact specifications:[Telerik Multi-Select](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/multiselect/index)